# SQL: subset data: select id when time_id for id satisfy a condition from another column

Tags: sql, filter, data-manipulation, having

I have a data (dt) in SQL like the following:

```
 ID     time_id  act  rd
 11        1      1    1
 11        2      4    1
 11        3      7    0
 12        1      8    1
 12        2      2    0
 12        3      4    1
 12        4      3    1
 12        5      4    1
 13        1      4    1
 13        2      1    0
 15        1      3    1
 16        1      8    0
 16        2      8    0
 16        3      8    0
 16        4      8    0
 16        5      8    0
```

and I want to take the subset of this data such that only ids (and their corresponding time_id, act, rd) that has time_id == 5 is retained. The desired output is the following

```
 ID     time_id  act  rd     
 12        1      8    1
 12        2      2    0
 12        3      4    1
 12        4      3    1
 12        5      4    1
 16        1      8    0
 16        2      8    0
 16        3      8    0
 16        4      8    0
 16        5      8    0
```

I know I should use having clause somehow but have not been successful so far (returns me empty outputs). below is my attempt:

SELECT * FROM dt
GROUP BY ID
Having min(time_id) == 5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select id from tablename where time_id = 5
```

returns all the `id`s that you want in the results.
Use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select *
from tablename
where id in (select id from tablename where time_id = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery with `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.time_id = 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH temp AS
(
SELECT id FROM tab WHERE time_id = 5
)
SELECT * FROM tab t join temp tp on(t.id=tp.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this query

```
 select * from table t1 join (select distinct ID from table t where time_id = 5) t2 on  t1.id =t2.id;
```